# Join Data from single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a property ownership table listing each land owner as a separate entry. To create more efficient mailers we want to create a view that can combine joint ownership between spouses.  Spouses have the same customer number however they have a separate address code to differentiate between individuals.  Each property has a single primary owner and can have any number of secondary owners.  I need to group owners of a property (PID) with the same customer number and include those that have a separate number.

For Example:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ PID      ║ OwnerName ║ OwnerType║CustomerNum ║AdressCode  ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║ 100      ║Smith,John ║Primary   ║SMI001      ║   01       ║
║ 100      ║Smith,Jane ║Secondary ║SMI001      ║   02       ║
║ 100      ║Smith,Dave ║Secondary ║SMI002      ║   01       ║
║ 150      ║Jones,Rob  ║Primary   ║JON001      ║   01       ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Should have an output like:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ PID      ║OwnerName1 ║OwnerName2║CustomerNum ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 100      ║Smith,John ║Smith,Jane║SMI001      ║
║ 100      ║Smith,Dave ║          ║SMI002      ║
║ 150      ║Jones,Rob  ║          ║JON001      ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

I used the following query:

```
Select
    O1.PID as PID,
    O1.OwnerName as OwnerName1,
    O2.OwnerName as OwnerName2,
    O1.CustomerNum
From ownertable O1 left outer join
    ownertable  O2 on O1.PID = O2.PID
Where O1.CustomerNum = o2.CustomerNum AND O1.OwnerType = 'Primary Owner'
```

The query seems to copy the first owner name into both name fields when there isn't a secondary owner and it also create a duplicate record inverting OwnerName1 and OwnerName2.  I'm not sure what to change in my query to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one :

```
Select  pid,
        IsNull(max(case when AdressCode = '01' then OwnerName end), '') as OwnerName1,
        IsNull(max(case when AdressCode = '02' then OwnerName end), '') as OwnerName2,
        customernum
from ownertable
group by pid, customernum
Order BY pid, customernum
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to `PIVOT` your result.  One option is to use `MAX` and `CASE` for this:

```
select pid, 
  max(case when ownertype='Primary' then OwnerName end) OwnerName1,
  max(case when ownertype='Secondary' then OwnerName end) OwnerName2,
  customernum
from ownertable
group by pid, customernum
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c52c0/1)

---

If the order matters (where sometimes `Secondary` should be `OwnerName1` as with `Smith,Dave`), you could use a `row_number`:

```
with cte as (
  select pid, ownername, ownertype, customernum,
    row_number() over (partition by pid, customernum 
                       order by ownertype) rn
  from ownertable
  )
select pid, 
  max(case when rn = 1 then OwnerName end) OwnerName1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then OwnerName end) OwnerName2,
  customernum
from cte
group by pid, customernum
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c52c0/3)